# AWS SES Conditional HTML Template + NodeJs

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-ses, aws-sdk-nodejs

I want to send a condition-based template in AWS SES Template.
i.e

```
 if (condition) {
  //  block of code to be executed if the condition is true
} else {
  //  block of code to be executed if the condition is false
}
```

Can anyone please tell me How I can achieve this in **AWS SES Template?**

**My goal is to send templates part on a condition based.**

Comment: Refer https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/send-personalized-email-advanced.html#send-personalized-email-advanced-conditionals

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you're looking for:

{{#if User.UserAttributes.FirstName.[0]}}

Hello {{User.UserAttributes.FirstName.[0]}},

{{else}}

Hello,

{{/if}}

Check https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/userguide/message-template-helpers.html for more info, examples and alternative conditional statements.

Comment: Yes, Thann You for your support. I have done this.

Comment: Can we add && condition in the {{#if}} block ?

Comment: @KishorPatidar Yes we can.